# On the integrability of vector fields

Tags: differential-geometry, smooth-manifolds

Let $X$ and $Y$ be a vector field on $M$ and satisfies $[X,Y]=X$.

If $X$ and $Y$ are pointwise linearly independent for some point $p$, then there is a sub manifold $N$ of $M$ such that $T_xN$ is spanned by $X$ and $Y$ by Frobenius theorem.

Are there any counterexample that such $N$ does not exists when $X$ and $Y$ are linearly dependent at point $p$?

Comment: If $N$ is a submanifold, the dimension of $T_xN$ is the same for all $x$. So, if the dimension of the span of $X,Y$ drops at some point $p$, there isn't such $N$.  The question is, do we have any example of $X,Y$ such that this happens? I don't.

Comment: @Thisismuchhealthier.: I'm on board with your first two sentences, but I'm confused by the second part. Are you pondering the existence of some $X,Y$ that satisfy $[X,Y]=X$ and are linearly dependent at $p$?

Comment: @squirrel Yes, and a few minutes of pondering did not produce such an example, hence my comment. (Differential geometry is not my strong suit.)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, here's an example. Let $M=\mathbb R^3$, and define
\begin{align*}
X = \frac{\partial}{\partial x}, \qquad Y =  (x+1) \frac{\partial}{\partial x}+ 3 z^2 \frac{\partial}{\partial y}+2y\frac{\partial}{\partial z} .
\end{align*}
Then $[X,Y]=X$, and $X$ and $Y$ are linearly independent everywhere except along the $x$-axis. 
Away from the $x$-axis, the integral manifolds are level sets of $f(x,y,z) = z^3 - y^2$. 
If there were an integral manifold $N$ containing the origin, by continuity it would have to be contained in the zero-set of $f$; but the zero set of $f$ is not a smooth manifold at the origin because it has a cusp-like fold along the $x$-axis.